# 32 bit or 64 bit for 13.04

Tags: 32-bit

Can I change from 64 bit to 32 bit without re-installing 13.04?

I believe that I installed it as a 64 bit, and am wondering if that is causing all of the problems that I am having since the installation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed 64-bit and it works then there is no issue.

All programs that are 32-bit will work on 64-bit, so no worries. If you could install 64-bit Ubuntu then you have a 64-bit capable CPU and everything will work, so relax.

What problems do you have? You need to eb very specific if we are going to be able to help you.

64-bit is just a CPU architecture and doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu it's only regarding the Kernel, and how large instructions the CPU can handle.

Comment: Foxfire freezes up, sometimes when opening.  Video player freezes up when opening sometimes.  Opening up OpenOffice documents sometimes freeze.

Comment: @bolobill stunds like bugs to me. How much RAM do you have? Is the system up to date?

Comment: 512 RAM,1 tb of hard drive

Comment: That's way too little ram to have a smooth experience! I wouldn't go under 2 gb. Try lubuntu and yes go with the 32-bit since it will use less ram.

Answer (score 0):

even if you can, it will not be simple quick or clean.  This will lead to doubts as to whether or not the new problems are the 32 bit incarnations of the old ones or new problems incurred due to the switch or even brand new ones associated with just running a 32 bit setup for that situation.

My advice when troubleshooting, is to eliminate as many unknowns and unusuals as possible, by having as standard a system as possible.  That way you can have a standard base to help identify what differences to everyone else's systems that are causing your problems.

Comment: I have been using Ubuntu for three or four years, but am not adept at changing things, so there is nothing that is altered in there that I have done.